# Duplicate Namespace Including Google Apps Script Library

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth, oauth-2.0

I've forked this [OAuth2 library for Google Apps Script](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2), uploaded it to my Drive as a separate Script, and swapped the SCRIPT ID of the upstream repo with my fork to test changes I've made to the library. However, when I run functions that call library functions, such as `OAuth2.createService`, I get this TypeError:

> Cannot find function createService in object [object Object]

The `OAuth` identifier is another level down, inside another `OAuth` object. So the script works with my library when run `OAuth2.OAuth2.createService`. [My fork](https://script.google.com/d/1jAZ1l2eclUF_vuhshoFyx7wcpHixwgGDZirdcub5xLchOuL6qJLcyGFs/edit?usp=sharing) doesn't have any changes that would do this.

It's not the biggest deal, but I want make a pull request with this sample code. So my question isn't so much about why isn't this code working, it's why is GAS include essentially the same library in these two different ways?

Here's how I've included the libraries in my script.
[image: Library Upload]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure that you are using the built code instead the library directly. You need to modify the code from `src` folder. Skip `dist` folder always.

[Issue #70](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/issues/70#issuecomment-312223803)